# How do you make command2 wait for command1 to exit when executing command1 | command2?

Tags: unix, browser, pipe, i3

I'm trying to pipe the output of dmenu to surf (browser) in order to browse a selected URL. I'm doing:

```
cat ~/.surf/bookmarks | dmenu | surf
```

but surf starts before dmenu has exited with my chosen URL. This means it doesn't open with the correct URL. I don't see what the problem is because dmenu prints the URL to standard output after a choice is made, and surf works taking a URL as its argument. To clarify, the bookmarks file just contains URLs on separate lines.

I'm using this in i3, as a bindsym. I also tried

```
surf (cat ~/.surf/bookmarks | dmenu)
```

fish shell syntax, as that is my shell.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `and surf works taking a URL as its argument.` You're piping it to stdin though.

Comment: maybe `surf $(cat ~/.surf/bookmarks | dmenu)`?

Comment: @Bodo thanks it worked! I had tried that with fish shell syntax (as in my terminal). However, it seems i3 exec uses bash. So, your version worked. If you give it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in tkauusl's comment, `surf` should get the URL as a command line argument, not piped to `stdin`.

For `bash` and POSIX compatible shells you can use this syntax:

```
surf $(cat ~/.surf/bookmarks | dmenu)
```

For other shells you might have to use

```
surf `cat ~/.surf/bookmarks | dmenu`
```

If the URL can contain spaces, you should quote the result of the command substitution.

```
surf "$(cat ~/.surf/bookmarks | dmenu)"
```